# How can i sql pivot column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pivot-table

I've seen a lot of questions that ask about pivot tables.Even if they don't know that they are asking about pivot tables, ......

- What is pivot?
- How do I pivot?
- how can i pivot this data?

```
+---------+----------+----------+
| Subject | Semester | Attendee |
+---------+----------+----------+
| ITB001  |        1 | John     |
| ITB001  |        1 | Bob      |
| ITB001  |        1 | Mickey   |
| ITB001  |        2 | Jenny    |
| ITB001  |        2 | James    |
| MKB114  |        1 | John     |
| MKB114  |        1 | Erica    |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

To
Like this

```
+----------+----------+----------------+
| Attendee | Semester | Subject        |
+----------+----------+----------------+
| John     |        1 | ITB001,MKB114  |
| Bob      |        1 | ITB001         |
+----------+----------+----------------+
```

Comment: <mysqli> and <sql-server>, that's an odd tag combo. Are you using MS SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: This doesn't look like pivoting, and looks more like string aggregation.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Please use an appropriate version-specific tag.

Comment: If, however, you want to find out what a pivot is, and how to pivot, a simple search would give you a *wealth* of resources.

Comment: Also I don't know that I like the duplicate, most of the answers don't seem to address, well, duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a pivot at all, it's string aggregation.

In SQL Server 2017+ or Azure SQL Database:

```
SELECT Attendee, Semester, Subjects = STRING_AGG(Subject, ',')
  FROM dbo.SomeTableName
  GROUP BY Attendee, Semester;
```

On older and unsupported versions, it's a heck of a lot uglier, not to mention inefficient:

```
SELECT ost.Attendee, ost.Semester, Subjects = STUFF((
  SELECT ',' + ist.Subject
    FROM dbo.SomeTableName AS ist
    WHERE ist.Attendee = ost.Attendee
      AND ist.Semester = ost.Semester
    FOR XML PATH(''), 
    TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM dbo.SomeTableName AS ost
GROUP BY ost.Attendee, ost.Semester;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bc70f503120db75063420b6f994bc74a)